# How to structure a VueJS/VueX application to reactively handle dynamic external data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a web application that is essentially broken into two components: a JavaScript application containing business logic, and a UI layer that allows users to drill into data generated by said application. For the UI layer I'm looking to make use of VueJS and VueX, but I'm currently wondering about best practice when it comes to integrating data from my JS application into the VueJS stack.

One approach I've tried is to essentially pass a reference to my application's core class as `data` to my Vue instance, like so:

```
this.vue = new Vue({
    el: '#ui-container',
    store,
    template: '<UI :app="app"/>',
    components: { UI },
    data: {
        app: app
    }
});
```

This allows me to pass around the instance as a `prop` to my various child components and does seem to work. But is there a better/more efficient way to handle this?

I'm currently using VueX to maintain state regarding various pieces of my UI - should I be keeping the app reference there? If so, what's the best way to handle this while making it possible for my components to re-render when data in the app instance changes?

Comment: Ideally the workflow is one-way - you use Vuex `getters` inside your components to get the current value of various parts in your data model (and to react on changes to these values) and you dispatch Vuex `actions` (which in turn commit `mutations`) when you need to change something in your data model. You do not modify the data model directly - only by Vuex `actions`.

Comment: @IVOGELOV The application side of things works independently of the VueJS stack, so data is indeed modified directly. Is this a deal breaker? Using the approach I mentioned I do see my components dynamically re-rendered when data is updated directly.

Comment: Vuex does not prevent you from modifying data directly (unless you specifically instruct it so) - it is just considered best practice to use actions and mutations. If you modify the data directly - Vuex is useless to you, just adds more code. Also watch out to avoid the pitfalls - adding/deleting object keys dynamically or changing array items by their index in the array.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I believe I haven't made my intentions very clear, sorry. I have dynamic data outside of the VueJS/VueX store that is updated periodically. Essentially I'm trying to figure out the most effective way of informing VueJS that this data has been mutated outside of VueJS, so that it can then ingest (likely via my VueX store) the updated data and have my components react accordingly.

Comment: Vue reacts on changes by creating observers on the data section. These observers are created when the Vue component is instantiated. If you do not change the structure of your data after that point in time and only change values - this is fine (but keep in mind http://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#Change_Detection_Caveats). Otherwise you will have to use `$forceUpdate()` method on the Vue instance (https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/356)